# Inverse Matrix of A

Tags: matrices

I would like to know how to write an inverse matrix off A. I have tried everything i could think off but i had no success. Could anybody give me a simple 2x2 example(I don´t know how to get -1 over the matrix bracket). Thank you               [image: this is what i gotta do]

Comment: Here : `\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}`.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! if you will show what you try so far (with small, complete document beginning with `\doccumentclass{...}` an ending with `\end{document}` we can help you. otherwise only advice: see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

Comment: You can put subscripts and superscripts on almost anything in LaTeX maths. You aren't limited to simple cases like `$x^2$.`

Comment: I have to do this A^-1=(A b c d)^-1 in matrix form

Comment: when i do it with bmatrix I get everything except -1s  and i have math package and everything else required

Comment: @IgorKrstulović,than please be so kind and edit your question and show what you have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'bmatrix*' env.; loads 'amsmath' package automatically
\begin{document}
Let
\[
A = \begin{bmatrix}
       a_{11} & a_{12} \\ 
       a_{21} & a_{22}
    \end{bmatrix}
\]
be a full-rank $2\times2$ matrix. 
Then $\det A\equiv\lvert A\rvert=a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}\ne0$ and 
\[
A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
          a_{11} & a_{12} \\ 
          a_{21} & a_{22}
       \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
      =\frac{1}{\lvert A\rvert}
       \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
           a_{22} & -a_{12} \\ 
          -a_{21} &  a_{11}
       \end{bmatrix*} \,.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what i was hoping for